# yacc program to convert arithmetic expression into postfix

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex, bnf, postfix-notation

I am new to lex and yacc programs.I have been trying to write a yacc program which takes as input an arithmetic expression and gives postfix notation as output.
The grammar which i am using is:
exp : exp + term
    | exp - term
    | term
term : term * factor
     | term / factor
     | factor
factor : num

This is my lex code:

```
 %{
extern int yylval;
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

[0-9]+  {yylval = atoi(yytext);return INTEGER;}
[ \t\n]     /* skip whitespace */
.   {return *yytext;}
%%

int yywrap(void) {
return 1;
}
```

This is my yacc program :

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
%token INTEGER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%%

E:  E '+' T  {printf("+");}
    | E '-' T {printf("-");}
    | T     
    ;

T:  T '*' F   {printf("*");}
    | T '/' F {printf("/");}
    | F
    ;     

F:  '(' E ')'
    | INTEGER {printf("%d",yylval);}
    ;   

%%

int main(){
    yyparse();
}

int yyerror (char *msg) {
    return printf ("error YACC: %s\n", msg);
}
```

But this code is compiling correctly.But output is not correct if '+' or '-' are used in the expression
For example input: 2+3
            output : 23 (instead of 23+)
Please help me in finding out the error in the code.
Thanks.

Comment: Your grammar only accepts a single expression. If you close the input after the expression, it will print correctly.

Comment: Also note that you do not need the T non-terminal because you specify the same using operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

If you input **2+3**, and nothing more, the parser doesn't know that you intended that to be a complete expression. It could be the start of the expression **2+3*4**. So the parser sits there and waits for more input.

Try to add an end-of-expression token, such as semicolon, to your grammar.

Answer (score 0):

\n { return(0); }

just add this line inside the rules section of your code in your lex file:)

Comment: Why's that? A little explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The infix and postfix notations are the results of walking an AST in different orders. So you have to start with building the AST to have something to walk in the chosen order *after* the AST is complete.

In the semantic actions you have to create nodes which point to the nodes they consist of. Then walk the tree after it's complete:

```
%start start

%%

start: E { walk_post_order($1); }
```

Comment: This really isn't true. The actions the OP has posted are sufficient to walk the parse tree. It isn't always necessary to build an AST at all: production compilers have been built without one.